# New users can't login sessions in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**I am practicing with a small project in Django that I got through a tutorial, but I have a problem and can't find the solution.**

**I have created a form to register new users, but when I do, the page returns me to the registration form instead of redirecting me to the login page**

**When you tried to enter the new user's data who is supposed to be 'already registered' to start the session. Receipt in template "Incorrect username or password"**

**However, when I try to login with the superuser I created via command line after installing Django. This one opens without problems**

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .forms import OrderForm, CustomerForm, CreateUserForm
from .filters import OrderFilter
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_value = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form_value.is_valid():
                form_value.save()
                user = form_value.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was create for {}'.format(user)) 
                return redirect('login')
        form_value = CreateUserForm
        context = {'form_key':form_value}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username_value=request.POST.get('username')
            password_value=request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username_value, password=password_value)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):

    orders_value = Order.objects.all()
    customer_value = Customer.objects.all()
    
    total_orders_value = orders_value.count()
    total_customers_value = customer_value.count()

    pending_value = orders_value.filter(status='Pending').count()
    delivered_value = orders_value.filter(status='Delivered').count()

    context = {'orders_key': orders_value, 'customer_key': customer_value,
    'total_orders_key':total_orders_value, 'pending_key': pending_value, 
    'delivered_key': delivered_value}

    return render (request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def products(request):
    products_value = Product.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'accounts/products.html', {'products_key': products_value})

@login_required(login_url='login')
def customer(request, pk_test):
    customer_value = Customer.objects.get(id=pk_test)

    orders_value = customer_value.order_set.all()
    orders_value_count = orders_value.count()

    myFilter_value = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset= orders_value)
    orders_value = myFilter_value.qs

    context = {'customer_key':customer_value, 
    'orders_key': orders_value, 
    'orders_key_count': orders_value_count,
    'myFilter_key':myFilter_value}
    return render (request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def createOrder(request, pk):
    OrderFormSet= inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order, fields=('product', 'status'), extra=10)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    form_set_value= OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none() ,instance=customer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_set_value= OrderFormSet(request.POST, instance=customer)
        if form_set_value.is_valid():
            form_set_value.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form_set_key':form_set_value}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def updateOrder(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    form_value = OrderForm(instance=order)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_value = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        if form_value.is_valid:
            form_value.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form_key':form_value}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def deleteOrder(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order.delete()
        return redirect('/')
    context={'item':order}
    return render (request, 'accounts/delete.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def createCustomer(request):
    form_value_cus = CustomerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_value_cus = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form_value_cus.is_valid:
            form_value_cus.save()
            return redirect ('/')
    context = {'form_key_cus':form_value_cus}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_form.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, fields
from .models import Order, Customer
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        # fields = ['customer', 'product']
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import SET_NULL

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
            ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
            ('Out Door', 'Out Door'),
            ) 
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    prince = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )
    
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),        

    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('products/', views.products, name="products"),
    path('customer/<int:pk_test>/', views.customer, name="customer"),

    path('create_order/<int:pk>', views.createOrder, name='create_order'),
    path('update_order/<int:pk>', views.updateOrder, name='update_order'),
    path('delete_order/<int:pk>', views.deleteOrder, name='delete_order'),
    path('create_customer/', views.createCustomer, name='create_customer'),
]
```

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: #7abecc !important;
        }
        .user_card {
            width: 350px;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            background: #74cfbf;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            border-radius: 5px;

        }

        .form_container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #form-title{
            color: #fff;
        }
        .login_btn {
            width: 100%;
            background: #33ccff !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
        .login_btn:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }
        .login_container {
            padding: 0 2rem;
        }
        .input-group-text {
            background: #f7ba5b !important;
            color: white !important;
            border: 0 !important;
            border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
        }
        .input_user,
        .input_pass:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h3 id="form-title">REGISTER ACCOUNT</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">

                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form_key.username}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form_key.email}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form_key.password1}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            {{form_key.password2}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                            <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Register Account">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                
                {{form_key.errors}}
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                        Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="ml-2">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
                        
        var form_fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
        form_fields[1].placeholder='Username..';
        form_fields[2].placeholder='Email..';
        form_fields[3].placeholder='Enter password...';
        form_fields[4].placeholder='Re-enter Password...';


        for (var field in form_fields){ 
            form_fields[field].className += ' form-control'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: #7abecc !important;
        }
        .user_card {
            width: 350px;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            background: #74cfbf;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            border-radius: 5px;

        }

        .form_container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #form-title{
            color: #fff;
            
        }

        .login_btn {
            width: 100%;
            background: #33ccff !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
        .login_btn:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }
        .login_container {
            padding: 0 2rem;
        }
        .input-group-text {
            background: #f7ba5b !important;
            color: white !important;
            border: 0 !important;
            border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
        }
        .input_user,
        .input_pass:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            outline: 0px !important;
        }

        #messages{
            background-color: grey;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">


                    <h3 id="form-title">LOGIN</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-control" >
                        </div>

                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                                <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
                
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <p id='messages'>{{message}}</p>
                {% endfor %}

                <div class="mt-4">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                        Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="ml-2">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Another thing I noticed is that when I register a new user and go to the administration panel, the new registered user does not appear in the section '' users '' within the administration panel, as there is no record within the database either.**

**Which makes me think that it may be a problem with the '' registerPage '' view but I can't really find the problem, if someone can help me and explain what the error is, that would be great; I am new to using Django and I want to learn the best way. Thank you very much for your cooperation**

**NOTE: By suggestions of one person, agg a 'print ()' in the function 'registerPage ()' to know if it was executing correctly and I did the registration of several users**

**views.py**

```
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_value = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form_value.is_valid():
                form_value.save()
                user = form_value.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was create for {}'.format(user))
                print('Execute') 
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'Account was not create') 
                print('Dont execute')
        form_value = CreateUserForm
        context = {'form_key':form_value}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

**Terminal**

```
[28/Oct/2021 18:47:53] ←[32m"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:47:54] ←[m"GET /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3265←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:47:56] ←[m"GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4322←[0m
Execute
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:19] ←[32m"POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:19] ←[m"GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3324←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:34] ←[32m"GET /products HTTP/1.1" 301 0←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:34] ←[32m"GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:34] ←[m"GET /login/?next=/products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3265←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:36] ←[m"GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4322←[0m
Dont execute
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:51] ←[m"POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4322←[0m
[28/Oct/2021 18:48:57] ←[m"GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3319←[0m
```

**Note that there are some that run fine and some that don't ... Please help me**

Comment: In the `registerPage` view, make an else condition for `form.is_valid()` and print a random message there. Then try to register to see if the `form.is_valid()` check actually goes through.

Comment: Can you show me an example? Please

Comment: Or just add a print() inside the form.is_valid() condition and see if the execution even gets there.

Comment: The 'print ()' part that I add in 'form value.is_valid ()' is not executed. Anything you can suggest to me? @EnePaul

Answer (score 0):

```
views.py 

  use

Else: 

  form_value = CreateUserForm
        context = {'form_key':form_value}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_value = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form_value.is_valid():
                form_value.save()
                user = form_value.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was create for {}'.format(user))
                print('Execute') 
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'Account was not create') 
                print('Dont execute')
#put else here
else:
        form_value = CreateUserForm
        context = {'form_key':form_value}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).